# The result of my sql query is repeated

Tags: php, pdo

This is the code I'm using:

```
$sql = "SELECT Student_ID
        FROM course_student
        WHERE Course_ID='$CourseID'";

$Lresult=$DBInstance->CallDB($sql);
print_r($Lresult);
```

The result i am getting is:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [Student_ID] => S10812345 [0] => S10812345 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [Student_ID] => S1081299 [0] => S1081299 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [Student_ID] => S1089922 [0] => S1089922 ) 
)
```

This is the result I want:

```
Array ( [0] => S10812345 [1] => S1081299 [2] => S1089922 )
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten something.

Comment: Guess you have to GROUP BY Student_ID

Comment: yah sorry about that I already posted the query

Answer (score 0):

Check your $Dbinstantse class method to exist 'fetchCol', or some other method that returns a linear array with the values from the first column
Or use array_map for convert your array to linear

php version < 5.3

```
$res = array_map( 
          create_function( '$item', 'return $item[\'Student_ID\'];'), 
          $array 
       );
```

php ver >= 5.3

```
$res = array_map( function ( $item ) { 
                      return $item['Student_ID']; 
                  }, 
                  $array 
       );
```